# Ruby operator and method invoking

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading

Assume that we have a class

```
class Foo
  def +   (element); end
  def add (element); end
end
```

Now we can invoke these two methods like:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.+('bar')
foo.add('bar')
```

And that's resonable. This is the right way of invoking methods.

My question is: Why we can do something like:

```
foo + 'bar'
```

but not:

```
foo add 'bar'
```

Does Ruby distinguish if method name is actually operator overloading? How does it work?

Comment: Not a bad question! +1

Comment: Ruby distinguishes strings that represent operators from other strings. So when you do `def +` it knows you are defining (or overloading) an existing operator. Since `add` isn't already an operator, it's treated as a normal method. You can define a custom operator using a gem, such as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874579/define-custom-ruby-operator

Comment: mbratch, I want to accept your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the things many people refer to as Ruby's syntax sugar. The language recognizes these mathematical operators as well as other ASCII symbol operators, such as the `<<` insertion operator, and allows them to be called with white space and without the method dot. This allows for a more natural usage of the method.

Your `#add` method is not recognized by Ruby to be a standard operator and so this syntax help is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby treats specific method names called also as a (subset of) operators differently. They can be invoked without a dot `.`, can be prepended to an owning object (do not require an argument, ie. *unary operators*) and have different precedence order then standard methods.

[Here](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4) is a fixed list of concrete `operator' methods which are not keywords and can be defined or overloaded (marked with Y).