# how can i rename a operator method with words, respecting sintax in ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators, rename, alias

I'm trying to add an alias to a class method that uses an operator in ruby. My problem is that i would like to keep the new alias with the sintax of the operator

def &(estrategia)
does something
end

I would like to have the same result doing Myclass.new & estrategia, but like this:
 Myclass.new with estrategia
Is there a way in ruby, to achieve this?

```
   class Trait
     def & (strategy)
        p "hi #{strategy}"
     end
   alias with &
  end

 Trait.new & "John"
 Trait.new with "John"
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Could you provide the code?

Comment: Yes, i just uploaded the code below. If you could help i'd be great

Comment: Please edit your original question. Also, please don't put a link to an image/an image but type the code so people can copy/paste and try it.

Comment: ohh sorry, it's my first post. I'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby has particular operators you can override, like `%`, `+`, and `&`, but you can't just invent arbitrary operators on a whim. You need to work with pre-existing ones.

This is a function of how the Ruby parser works. It can only identify a pre-defined set of symbols outside of regular method calls.

`Trait.new.with x` is a method call, equivalent to `Trait.new.send(:with, x)`, while `Trait.new with x` is `Trait.new(with(x))` which is not what you want.

Your `alias` creates a *method*, it does not create an operator. You cannot create a brand-new operator.

You're going to have to decide between the two forms `x & y` vs. `x.with y`.

Comment: well i'll stick to ruby operators then haha,thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss `.`with your method call.

```rb
class Trait
     def & (strategy)
        p "hi #{strategy}"
     end
   alias with &
end

Trait.new.& "John"
Trait.new.with "John"
```

Comment: No, what i would like to achieve, if possible, is to do it without the "."

Answer (score 0):

The `&` is a default operator in Ruby and you can override with your method. But `with` is not an operator. In this case, you will need to add a new operator to Ruby, which is kind of tricky.
There is a discussion about adding new operator in Ruby here [Define custom Ruby operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874579/define-custom-ruby-operator) but I don't think it's worth to do that.