# Vector addition in Object Oriented Ruby

Tags: ruby, vector

I have to create class in Ruby with constructor which initialize two dimensional vector. X and Y are length of vector. In this class I have to create method which will add two vectors which are objects of class Vector2D.

```
class Vector2D
    def initialize(x, y)
        @x = x
        @y = y
    end
    def add 
        return "Vector addition"
    end
end

vector1 = Vector2D.new(3,4)
vector2 = Vector2D.new(1,2)

puts vector1.add
```

I don't know how to implement "add" method. I don't know how to send this two vectors as parameters and I don't know on which object I have to call this method.

Comment: Perhaps this link will help https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Writing_methods

Comment: You may want to look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556124/ruby-defining-operator-procedure  to implement a method that will allow you to use `+` to add two vectors using code like `vector1 + vector2`

Answer (score 3):

I believe this may be what you want.

**Code**

```
class Vector2D
  attr_reader :x

  def initialize(*x)
    @x = x
  end

  def add(other)
    x.zip(other.x).map { |x,y| x+y }
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
vector1 = Vector2D.new(3,4)
vector2 = Vector2D.new(1,2)

vector1.add(vector2)
  #=> [4, 6]
```

The method works for vectors of any size, though to add one to another they must must of course be the same size.

```
Vector2D.new(1,2,3,4).add Vector2D.new(5,6,7,8)
  #=> [6, 8, 10, 12] 
Vector2D.new(1).add Vector2D.new(2)
  #=> [3] 
Vector2D.new().add Vector2D.new()
  #=> []
```

**Explanation**

`initialize` is called with the argument `*x`. `*` is called the "splat" operator. [This link](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/) gives a good explanation of how it is used. Had you passed an array to [Class::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-c-new) (`Vector2D.new([3,4])`) you wouldn't need the splat operator. (More on that below.)

In `add` we compute

```
a = vector1.x.zip(vector2.x)
  #=> [[3, 1], [4, 2]]
```

then

```
a.map { |x,y| x+y }
  #=> [4, 6]
```

Note

```
x.zip(other.x).map { |x,y| x+y }
```

is the same as

```
self.x.zip(other.x).map { |x,y| x+y }
```

That's because when a method (here the getter `x`) does not have an explicit receiver (as it would if we wrote `self.x`, `self` being the receiver), Ruby assumes the receiver is `self`. You will often see `self.my_method`, when `my_method` would have saficed. Some Rubiests elect the former because they think it's clearer (even though they knows it's unnecessary). I don't happen to be in that camp.

We could instead write

```
@x.zip(other.x).map { |x,y| x+y }
```

referencing the instance variable `@x` directly, rather than through its getter. Both ways are fine.

**Observations**

It may be preferable to write:

```
  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
  end
```

and

```
vector1 = Vector2D.new([3,4])
```

to emphasize you are passing an array.

When two arrays are the same length you can use [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) and [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) interchangeably:

```
def add(other)
  [x, other.x].transpose.map { |y,z| y+z }
end
```

That's because

```
[3,4].zip([1,2])
  #=> [[3, 1], [4, 2]] 
[[3,4], [1,2]].transpose
  #=> [[3, 1], [4, 2]]
```

Comment: I think that varargs constructor as well as map/zip/transpose are overkill and probably way to advanced for the OP.
Also i'd return a Vector2D as result of the operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add two vectors in a OO way, then you pass one vector as argument to the other when you send the `add` message and you return a result (which can be nil).

In general this looks like:

```
result = receiver.message(argument)
```

So your vector should have a `add` method which takes the other vector as param. I'd return a new vector as result (but you could also return an array with x/y) which would allow you to continue your calculations.

```
class Vector2D
  attr_reader :x, :y

  def initialize(x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end

  def add(other)
    Vector2D.new(x + other.x, y + other.y)
  end

  def inspect
    "(#{x},#{y})"
  end
end


vector1 = Vector2D.new(3,4)
vector2 = Vector2D.new(1,2)

vector3 = vector1.add(vector2)

p vector1 # => (3,4)
p vector2 # => (1,2)
p vector3 # => (4,6)
p vector3.add(vector3) # )> (8,12)
```

In a similar way you can add other operations which are useful to vector calculations. Perhaps `length` or `subtract` and so on.

And if you want to add some *syntactic sugar* you can alias the method `add` to `+`. Add the following line *after* the definition of `add`

```
alias_method :+, :add
```

which will enable you to write

```
vector3 = vector1 + vector2
```

Comment: I'm not sure the OP wants the method to only work only with arrays having two elements.

Comment: I always thought vectors were "1D".

Comment: I pass two integers. A 2D vector has exactly two "coordinates". If it's only one, then it is a scalar.